# What are possible causes for LESS "unrecognized input" on a class selector?

Tags: node.js, less

LESS is throwing

```
ParseError: Unrecognized input in [filepath] on line 120, column 3:
119  .transition(width 0.32s, height 0.32s, left 0.32s, top 0.32s);
120  .room {
121    display: inline-block;
```

Column 3 is the `.`. I've looked through my code and can't find any reason for this. Commenting out the statement before it doesn't change the result. Commenting out `.room{` and its matching `}` results in the second-next class declaration being flagged, equally as inexplicably.

I've done some research but most of the info out there on LESS "Unrecognized input" has to do with @import declarations or variable use, neither of which I'm doing right here.

Because LESS can be quite involved, I'm put up a repo for my problematic code: https://github.com/theqwertman/less-sample-for-debugging

Using LESS version 1.7.5 installed through NPM globally.

Comment: in your style.less line 147 the leading . for the `.fa-icon();` call is missing? You seem to call the .transition() with four arguments and vendor-prefixes.less:.transition(@transition) only accepts one try `.transition(~"width 0.32s, height 0.32s, left 0.32s, top 0.32s");`

Comment: That did the trick. I'm used to Stylus which is much easier on mixins with a variable number of arguments. Thank you!